# How to identify Amazon AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there a system file that authoritatively tells me if a host is an Amazon AWS EC2 instance?

Bonus point: without installing anything new, is there a command that will tell me some basic parameters of an EC2 instance?

Context:
~~~~~~~~
I have a script that gathers information.
If I run the script on an EC2 instance, some "standard" commands are not available, 
for example: dmidecode (this gives me practically nothing), or virt-what.

I am aware of /usr/bin/ec2-describe-instances, or wget for metadata script, or wget 
for individual components reported by metadata, but I don't want to install anything
new, and I need the tool to describe the host itself (since the script runs locally), 
not to inquire another host, or pass a key that I must obtain from yet another script 
that I must install first.
Maybe wget for a specific metadata info is the best tool I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I cannot guarantee this will work on any other AMI than Ubuntu 12.04 (I am using ami-8e987ef9) - please test yourself.

Here is what you might want to check out if you **really** want to avoid getting this info from the *magic* IP `169.254.169.254` and metadata as @Rico suggested:

```
### Datasource EC2
ubuntu@ip-10-33-59-70:~$ cat /var/lib/cloud/instance/datasource 
cloudinit.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2: DataSourceEc2
ubuntu@ip-10-33-59-70:~$ cat /var/lib/cloud/data/previous-datasource 
cloudinit.DataSourceEc2.DataSourceEc2: DataSourceEc2

### Hostname
ubuntu@ip-10-33-59-70:~$ cat /var/lib/cloud/data/previous-hostname 
ip-10-33-59-70

### Instance ID
ubuntu@ip-10-33-59-70:~$ cat /var/lib/cloud/data/previous-instance-id 
i-280ace69

### Instance ID also (check out instance symlink)
ubuntu@ip-10-33-59-70:/var/lib/cloud$ ls -al | grep instance
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   22 Jan 29 22:00 instance -> ./instances/i-280ace69
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jan 29 22:00 instances
```

Maybe looking around `/var/lib/cloud` will give you some info that you need without using `curl`.

I would rather suggest using the *magic IP* with metadata though.

On Ubuntu 12.04 there's also `/usr/bin/ec2metadata`, a util written in Python that actually queries `169.254.169.254`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the standard way of querying the metadata

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

For a list of all the metadata options:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

If you get anything other than a '200' then it means it's not an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ cat /sys/hypervisor/uuid
```

For HVM:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo dmidecode --string system-uuid
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid
```

If the strings start with "ec2" or "EC2", the OS is running on an EC2 instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/identify_ec2_instances.html